# Spring driven unit tests with imported spring config files

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have my Spring configuration files broken out with a primary config file for high level things, and then category specific configurations broken out into their own config files. So my resources directory goes a little something like this

```
resources/
  appContext.xml
  spring/
    domain1.xml
    domain2.xml
    domain3.xml
```

appContext.xml is my main Spring application context file, and it has `<import resource="domain*.xml"/>` elements for each sub XML config file.

I'm trying to write a junit functional test that needs to override only the domain1.xml config file, with say testDomain1.xml.  But all the other spring XML files stay the same.

Using the Spring unit test attributes, how can I tell Spring to load appContext.xml, but instead of importing domain1.xml, import testDomain1.xml?

Comment: If you are using Spring 3.1+, use profiles.

Comment: Just have a separate test app context